# Android: Navigation Drawer vertical shadow

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, shadow

I have implemented a `NavigationDrawer` in my application.  I would like to know how I can add a vertical shadow effect which is below the main Fragment, similar to the picture below.

[image]

I have one image on my drawable with the shadow image. It's called "drawer_shadow.9" but I don't know how I can implement this inside my `NavigationDrawer`.

Comment: No problem.  I wanted to add in the image for you because I wanted to help.  Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Is `drawer_shadow.9` also useable for the right-side drawer?

Comment: yes, of course @AlexanderFarber you need get the correct `drawer_shadow.9`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You will need to use a drawable for the shadow. Use the `setDrawerShadow` method on the navigationDrawer object. For example:

```
navigationDrawer.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.someDrawable, GravityCompat.START);
```

Link to the official document: [setDrawerShadow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#setDrawerShadow(int,%20int))

Hope this helps

Comment: Is there a way to do it in the xml?

Comment: Can you put the information for the `R.drawable.someDrawable` part. Do you have a sample for that? Is it a drawable png file or is more like a gradient through xml?

Comment: I was able to find a .png file called drawer_shadow.9.png  it's a 9 patch file included in the Google sample code. http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/NavigationDrawer.zip

Answer (score 2):

(Drawer on right side) Activity layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    ...
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/drawer_shadow"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="-20dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="-20dp" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
        android:name="com.....HomeDrawer"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        tools:layout="@layout/drawer_home" />

</LinearLayout></android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

draver shadow:

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#00FFFFFF"
            android:endColor="#f2e9e9e9"
            android:type="linear" />
        <size
            android:height="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:width="5dp">
        </size>
    </shape>
```

effect:

[image]